# document.registerElement extending HTMLInputElement prototype while using custom tag name to avoid implicit browser style

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

My goal is two-fold:

- Display an HTML element which keeps track of its 'checked' state and triggers 'change' events without having to manually implement that code myself.
- Not fight with the browser's implicit styling of the  element with `-webkit-appearance: none` and more fussing.

I only need to support the current, stable channel of Google Chrome. As such, I do not have much concern for compatibility with non-modern browsers.

I've approached the problem by using [document.registerElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.registerElement). With this method, I register a new tag, `custom-checkbox`, and inform the browser that I would like this tag to inherit from input.

From there, I need to setup the fact that this input's type is checkbox. To do so, I set its type in the `createdCallback` method which is ran when the HTML element is created.

This code has some issues:

- It works when I do not use a custom tag and instead leverage the `is` property to inform the browser that the input 'is' a `custom-checkbox`. However, using an `<input>` tag causes the browser to take over styling the element. I do not wish to have that happen.
- When using the custom tag, the `createdCallback` method is not ran. As such, the element does not setup the fact that it is a checkbox and it does not fire 'change' events when clicked.

What am I missing?

```js
var proto = Object.create(HTMLInputElement.prototype);
proto.createdCallback = function() {
  console.log('createdCallback has ran for: ', this);
  this.type = "checkbox";
};

document.registerElement("custom-checkbox", {
  prototype: proto,
  extends: 'input'
});

$('.custom-checkbox').change(function() {
  console.log('change event handler has ran for:', this);
});
```

```css
.custom-checkbox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<custom-checkbox class="custom-checkbox"></custom-checkbox>

<input is='custom-checkbox' class="custom-checkbox">
```

Comment: 1; maybe the element is not there when you bind the event? 2; maybe $.change doesn't recognized the tag, try elm.addEventListener() instead.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue (2). `createdCallback` only seems to get called when custom elements are created in-code immediately after registering the element. This is most likely because when the `<custom-checkbox>` tag is rendered, the event listener `createdCallback` has not binded. I'm going to try https://www.polymer-project.org/ as it has better support across browsers/support

Answer (score 1):

I can duplicate your issue where the `createdCallback` method does not fire when inserting a `<custom-element>` tag onto the page declared using `HTML`. I'm using Chrome version `39.0.2171.99`

I believe this is because when my `<custom-element>` is rendered, the event listener `createCallback` has not binded.

Bear in mind custom elements is not yet a defined standard ([see this](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/))

However, using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) solved the issue for me, using custom tags in `HTML` does fire what Polymer refers to as the `create` event/callback.

I would suggest you use [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org), it has better browser support to.